Ubuntu 24.04 DNS resolution for local machines
I am looking for installing Ubuntu 24.04 Desktop machines in order to run a MySQL server. When installing with the graphical UI, there is an option to join Active Directory, which I wanted to do. Before joining the domain, I switched from automatic DNS to manual, and entered the address of my domain controller (which is also DNS server). This works for Windows machines, but the Ubuntu machine still doesn't recognize the domain. It seems like local hostnames are not resolved and lead to following messages :
ping vm001 (my DC hostname) : Temporary failure in name resolution
ping mydomain.local : Name or service not known
Before giving some details about what I tried, is there a known issue on this point ? I installed a new machine, so no legacy version could interfear.
Thanks a lot for those who may help.

Holding back the details means little chance of any help.
